# How to apply shadow to an over-arching polygon formed by two divs

Tags: css

I need to apply box-shadow for an overarching polygon. The polygon is actually made up of two divs, the overarching box is one div by itself. As you could perhaps tell by the shadow effect of the image, noticing how the shadow for the bigger div overlaps the inset shadow of the overarching div. Any way to make the shadow look more uniform and blended together as a whole?

styling for overarching box:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) inset
```

styling for bigger div:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 30px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75)
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code, JSFiddle?

Comment: Would need the html to properly answer this. There are a number of issues that arise with this problem, but my best guess would be to create a wrapper to the top element which would create the border and then the menu element would need a margin-bottom:-50px; with a #fff background to cover the other shadow. Both items could also be one and the same using css :before and :after and then applying the shadow inset onto that one item

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer would something like that:

```
#base {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 30px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px 0 rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) inset;
}
#box:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255,0), rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.75) 10%,rgba(250, 250, 250,0.75) 90%, rgba(255, 255, 255,0));
}
```

In the first styles I am trying to reproduce your layout, I hope that it is more or less accurate.

Then I create a pseudo element, positioned on the problematic area. In this pseudo element I set a background that is a gradient from white transparent in the borders to slight gray in the center. This way I leave the shadow visible in the borders, and in the center I set the color that I want.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/HsaWk/)

It is not perfect, but it demonstrates the idea.

How it should look it's also a matter of taste; I don't know exactly what you are looking for.

Any way, playing with color stops, I think that you can get exactly what you want